# Deploy windows service in Serverless

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, serverless, aws-serverless

I am new in AWS. I have Windows Service, WCF Service and Web API running on Windows Server. Is it possible to deploy Windows Service, WCF Service and Web API in Serveless environment? Or is there any alternate way to deploy in Serverless? i.e. replace windows service with Web Service. Any help will be appreciated.